# get the number of video view count from youtube channel in android

Tags: android, youtube

I want to display the list of videos for the specific youtube channel. I successfully displayed all the videos for the specific channel in the android's list view but I also want to display the number of views for the videos in the same listview on each row.

I fetched the json data using [this](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCxxx4M3jP9HcKLHJ0dFLe7g&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyBvuEzoL3_rdCuOs7wpvVxLlpIa8kVddcs) url

but this api doesn't provide the number of views for the videos. Is there any way you guys had tried yet ? I found some solution but those are for single video only.

Comment: what you want? total number of video in channel?

Comment: I want number of views that each video has so that I can display inside my listview

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=hqepb5hzuB0&key={YOUR-API-KEY} have you try this? that responce in get `viewCount` array or object

Comment: ya but it is for only on video at a time but I want to get while fetching the channel data